# How to get the closest revision to the given one that contains other changes than .hgtags only?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a revision hash key. I would like to get the closest revision that contains anything, but the .hgtags.

For instance, consider the following fragment of a Mercurial history:

```
D:\CI\NC\8.0>hg log -l3 -b 8.0 -v
changeset:   1768:633cf1f61665
branch:      8.0
tag:         tip
user:        ci
date:        Wed Nov 16 21:06:20 2011 +0200
files:       .hgtags
description:
Replaced tag 'good.NC.16' with 'rejected.NC.16' for changeset 9451e8f187b1


changeset:   1767:6cad328c622c
branch:      8.0
parent:      1765:9451e8f187b1
user:        ci
date:        Wed Nov 16 21:04:26 2011 +0200
files:       .hgtags
description:
Added tag 'good.NC.16' for changeset 9451e8f187b1


changeset:   1765:9451e8f187b1
branch:      8.0
tag:         rejected.NC.16
user:        gilad
date:        Tue Nov 15 18:26:09 2011 +0200
files:       .hgignore
description:
update
```

In this case, if the given revision is `633cf1f61665`, then I am looking for the revision `9451e8f187b1`, because it is the closest one, which contains not just .hgtags, but something else.

How, given `633cf1f61665`, can I locate `9451e8f187b1` using as few hg.exe invocations as possible?

**EDIT**

I have fixed the output, it should have displayed revisions from the same branch.

**EDIT2**

I will try to explain myself. Let us define two notions:

- A dull changeset - the one created by the `hg tag` action.
- An interesting changeset - any non dull changeset.

So, my question can be rephrased like so:

```
Given an arbitrary revision (dull or interesting) I need to find the closest
interesting revision belonging to the same named branch using as few hg invocations
as possible.
```

For instance, given `633cf1f61665` or `6cad328c622c` or `9451e8f187b1` the required revision is `9451e8f187b1`.

Comment: Why do you want that changeset? Do you really want "previous tagged changeset"?

Comment: I have edited the question, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
$ hg log -r "max(::REV and not file(.hgtags))"
```

and see if that does what you want. See `hg help revsets` for more information about the query language.

You can make a revset alias for this if you use it often:

```
[revsetalias]
interesting($1) = max(::$1 and not file(.hgtags))
```

and then use `hg log -r "interesting(123)"` in the future.

Comment: Bingo. BTW, according to the docs it can be written even shorter - `hg log -r "last(::15400 - file(.hgtags), 1)"`

Comment: Yeah, you can use `-` if you prefer. I've updated the answer a little and replaced `last(..., 1)` with the simpler `max(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, but calling it `not-tagged` is wrong. The found revision can be tagged alright, it is just that that revision does not record the tagging action itself.

Comment: Yeah, `non-tagged` was not the best name — the `-` was seen as the set operator! :-) I've given it a better name now.

Comment: Hey I wanted to get revision just before the given revision. What do i use?  hg log -r "max(::REV)" gives the same revision detail!

Comment: @Srinivas: have you looked at `hg help revsets`? There you will find `p1(...)` which gives you the first parent of whatever `...` is. I think that's what you're looking for!